# How to get prospects based on custom field in Pardot?

Tags: api, php, pardot

We have 2 millions prospects in our Pardot account and we want to get some of the prospects. How to get those prospects based on custom field? 
We use Pardot API version 4 in our code base, but there's no search criteria by custom field.

I was trying to query all of our prospects by code, output mode equals simple and filter all custom field by a value, due to each query has a 200 results limit, I have to do this process many times. But during the running of the code, it stops at some point and I couldn't keep continue query that unless running from the beginning. There's no problem with daily API call limit and api_key timeout, I checked them.

Is there any better way to get that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with API key i.e. it expires after one hour of processing.
You need to write logic of generating the new key on expiration.
Something like below:

```
      do{
            //reset
            invalidAPIKey=false;
            api_key = getAPIKey();
            getData();
        }while(invalidAPIKey);
```

getData() will be recursively called until there is no record, like below:

```
//recursive condition
if(obj.get("result") == null){

    if(json.containsKey("err_code")){
        String errCode = json.get("err_code").toString();
        //invalid API key
        if(errCode != null && errCode.equals("1")){
            //update flag
            invalidAPIKey=true;
        }//api error
    }

    return;
}
//recursive call to get all possible items
getData();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I got the customized list by using Pardot console, create a rule, execute it and save the prospect to a new list, then export it. Thanks, anyway.